# SQLite - user defined function to work with relational data

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization, user-defined-functions

The SQLite database I'm working on stores named polygons, each consisting of some points, the tables are "polygons" (id, name) and "points" (x, y, polygon_id).
Now, given a point coordinates, I need to query all the polygons which are intersected by the point. 
My current solution (see below) is very slow, please help me **optimize it**

```
$dbh->sqliteCreateFunction('mgPoint', 'sqlite_point', 2);
function sqlite_point($sid, $pt){
    $points = query("SELECT x,y FROM points WHERE polygon_id = $sid")->all();
    return is_point_in_polygon($pt, $points);
}
//... and the usage ...
query("SELECT * FROM polygon s WHERE mgPoint(s.id, :p)", array('p' => $pt));
```

Comment: I haven't used SQLite yet but have you tried to create an index on polygon_id in both tables. I suppose it is already the case for the table polygon since it should be the primary key but wwho knows?

Comment: yeah, I do have an index on points.polygon_id, it decreased the execution time ~ 4x, but it is still way too long.

Comment: maybe you should compute a bounding box on those polygons and use sqlite's 2d indexing to prefilter your containment queries.